# Has the Naruto Anime deviated from the Manga

Tags: naruto, anime-production

In anime that were adapted from a manga, if it follows the manga, it would either follow it faithfully (Fullmetal Alchemist Brotherhood) or deviate from the manga's plot line (Oran High School Host Club, Original Fullmetal Alchemist). In my experience, anime deviations from manga normally occur because the manga is still ongoing and original filler is not enough.

Given how both the Naruto anime and manga are still ongoing, I am wondering if the anime of Naruto has deviated from the manga to the point where it could break continuity with the manga

For example, the 2003 Fullmetal Alchemist anime breaks continuity:

> at Laboratory 5 or when we learn who Sloth and Wrath are

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As far as I can remember and can find on-line the naruto anime does not/barely deviate from the manga. The main differences between the anime and manga is that the anime uses a occasional filler

> They added many small details in the stories which really supports the plot and makes it more interesting. However, like almost all manga-turned-anime series, there are filler episodes, though thankfully not too many, and not all bad.

Comment: Not too many, you say? Your tolerance limit is definitely OVER 9000!!

Comment: @Happy well. I watched bleach. With fillers in fillers...

Comment: Uhm, yeah, but they didn't need to change the series title to Bleach Shippuden owing to fillers. As for Bleach, I found the filler arcs, Fake Shinigami Arc and Zanpakuto Rebellion Arc, better than the main arcs. The two Damsel in Distress arcs, one each for Rukia and Orihime, dragged on for too long. Even the "level 3" battles, like the one between Ishida and Cirucci dragged on for something like 10 episodes.

Comment: @Happy not even Naruto is immune to that meme

Comment: @Happy that reminded me of DBZ with Goku shouting and trying to reach super saiyan mode for 2 episodes.