# What is the longest battle in anime?

Tags: anime-history

So happys comment actually trigged my curiosity.

> Uhm, yeah, but they didn't need to change the series title to Bleach Shippuden owing to fillers. As for Bleach, I found the filler arcs, Fake Shinigami Arc and Zanpakuto Rebellion Arc, better than the main arcs. The two Damsel in Distress arcs, one each for Rukia and Orihime, dragged on for too long. Even the "level 3" battles, like the one between Ishida and Cirucci dragged on for something like 10 episodes. –  Happy Dec 5 '13 at 14:12  - [Has the Naruto Anime deviated from the Manga](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/6136/has-the-naruto-anime-deviated-from-the-manga/6147#6147)

There are allot of series out there that hold long/stretched battles, such as Bleach, Naruto, Dragon ball. But which series currently holds the record for longest battle? And I am not talking about in battle speeches. I am talking about actually fighting screen time, and the amount of episodes it is stretched over.

Comment: So I suppose DBZ (Frieza vs. Goku & Company) is out then, since about 12 episodes of that is just *pure conversation*...

Comment: This might be hard to determine and will always have a possibility to change, making the old answer obsolete.

Comment: @kuwaly. Yes it will take some research. And the chance it changes is there. But I dont think this will change very often.

Comment: Is this a broad question?

Comment: @MiharuDante That definitely not.. It's rather specific at that...

Comment: The issue with this question is that (in principle) one must have knowledge of all anime ever created in order to correctly answer it. (In my opinion, it's also trivial and uninteresting, but that's no reason to close a question.)

Comment: @senshin All anime created? I don't usually see fights in romance anime, and when they are there they don't usually last longer then a few frames. Excludes quite a few, but yeah you would need a general knowledge of most action related animes.

Comment: [Here's](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=njvgKUSR8Ss) the full battle VS Freeza battle in it's entirety.

Comment: How would you even define "fighting screen time" and "episodes it is stretched over"? most of the time it starts to just recap and "next time" if they are stalling for time, and cut back and forth between different scenes - also, what defines a battle?

Comment: Erm......definition of battle:  " 1.
a hostile encounter or engagement between opposing military forces:////Subdefinition of clash between two people.   Lets call a fight between two people a duel, just to make things easier.     There are lots of long winded duels in anime.....but for me to think of battles, I have to include all the Macross/Gundam/Votoms battles, which some of them take place over a few episodes.